# Access facter variable from within ruby

Tags: ruby, scope, puppet, facter

Is it possible to access a facter variable from within ruby?

```
if %{virtual} == 'virtualbox'
  result = 'changeit'
else
  result = c[1]['passwd']
end
```

So `$::virtual` is a variable in facter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method depends on which Ruby function API you're using. If you're using the current [4.x API](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/functions_ruby_overview.html) (your function is at `lib/puppet/functions/*.rb`) then:

```
if closure_scope['facts']['virtual'] == 'virtualbox'
```

Docs: [Writing functions in Ruby: Accessing Puppet variables](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.10/functions_ruby_implementation.html#accessing-puppet-variables)

Or if you're using the legacy 3.x compatible API (your function is at `lib/puppet/parser/functions/*.rb`) then:

```
if lookupvar('virtual') == 'virtualbox'
```

Docs: [The legacy Ruby functions API: Using Facts and Variables](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/functions_legacy.html#using-facts-and-variables)

Comment: I use the current 4.x API. So i try the first approach but i get an "undefined local variable or method scope" error. So maybe there is still something missing?

Comment: I missed "scope = closure_scope" in side the method. After adding this i can access the content of "scope". Thx

Comment: Oops, I've fixed the answer to simply use `closure_scope`.